# NumberFormatException when converting Integer String in Java

Tags: java

I declare this variable:

```
private String numCarteBancaireValide=String.valueOf(((Integer.parseInt(Config.NUM_CARTE_BANCAIRE_VALIDE)   ) + (Integer.parseInt("0000000000000001"))));
Config.NUM_CARTE_BANCAIRE_VALIDE is a string.
```

After Execution, I receive this error message :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4111111111111111"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Please, Can you give your advices ?

Comment: Credit Card numbers are not integers and probably should not be treated as such; they are strings,

Answer (score 4):

Use `Long.parseLong()`, as your parameter is too large for an `Integer`. (Maximum for an integer is `2147483647`)

PS: using `Integer.parseInt("0000000000000001")` doesn't make much sense either, you could replace this with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The `4111111111111111` (which most likely is the value of `Config.NUM_CARTE_BANCAIRE_VALIDE`) overflows the `Integer` type.

Better try with:

```
//if you need a primitive
long value = Long.parseLong(Config.NUM_CARTE_BANCAIRE_VALIDE);
```

or

```
//if you need a wrapper
Long value = Long.valueOf(Config.NUM_CARTE_BANCAIRE_VALIDE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value of integer is 2147483647. So you need to use `Long.parseLong` instead to parse  4111111111111111. Something like this:

```
long l = Long.parseLong("4111111111111111");
```

**On a side note:**

As Alex has commented, if this number is representing a credit card number then you can treat it like a `string` instead of changing to `long` as there is no arithmetic calculations involved with the credit card numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` will attempt to parse an integer from a `String`.

Your `"4111111111111111"` `String` does not represent an valid Java integer type, as its value would be `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Use `Long.parseLong` instead.